# How to update m2m connection in overloaded save

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have library project. i have book and order model. the user can order many books at once, bu i have error.

this is my code ->

book model ->

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('name'))
    Condition = models.IntegerField(default=10,verbose_name=_('condition'))
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('author'))
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=100, verbose_name=_('quantity'))
    branch = models.ManyToManyField(Branch, verbose_name=_('branch'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Order(models.Model):
    book=models.ManyToManyField(Book, verbose_name=_('book'))
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('user'))
    branch=models.ForeignKey(Branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('branch'))
    start_date=models.DateField(verbose_name=_('start'))
    end_date=models.DateField(verbose_name=_('finish'))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        if not self.pk:
            # self.book.quantity -= 1
            for i in self.book:
                i.quantity -= 1
                i.save()
            self.end_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days=14)
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when i save i have this error ->**"<Order: d@gmail.com>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `.add()` method before you save the `Order` model?
If so then try saving the model object first before adding m2m objects.

For eg: `order = Order(user=<user>, branch=<branch>, start_date=<start_date>, end_date=<end_date>)` then `order.save()` and finally `order.book.add(<book1>, <book2>)` and so on.

Also i see in `save()` method you have used `for i in self.book` but you need to use `self.book.all()`